# What territories are included in Mainland China?

Tags: china, terminology

Please let me know what does it mean by **Mainland China**. Is it excluding Hong-Kong and Macau? What are the cities/ towns comprising Mainland China?

Comment: Welcome to Travel.SE. It is a little unclear what relationship your question has to travel; there are hundreds of thousands of cities and towns involved in any definition of *mainland China*, and you have not demonstrated what research you have attempted on your own. Please take the site [tour] and review the [help], and then [edit](http://travel.stackexchange.com/posts/64458/edit) your question to include more context, and we may be better-equipped to help you.

Comment: I always thought is was the China on the "continent" and excluding Hong-Kong and Macau (because they were foreign territories), and obviously Taiwan because it is (on) an island.

Comment: We need a bit more context than that. It could be referring to PRC/ROC ("China"/"Taiwan"). It could be reffering to bulk of PRC vs the SARs of Hong Kong and Macau. It could literally be referring to the continental landmass of China. @Max I think being run by a different government is an important part of the Taiwan part of that. What about Hainan - an Island the same size as Taiwan, but administrativly a full part of the PRC.

Answer (score 8):

Usually, "Mainland China" refers to the People's Republic of China, excluding

- Taiwan
- the Hong Kong SAR
- the Macau SAR

However, it may vary depending on context: it may for instance include Hong Kong and Macau while excluding Taiwan (mostly if this is in a Taiwanese context).

Comment: +1 Yes, and, without additional context, the term definitely includes Hainan and other islands that are controlled by the PRC government but are not geographically part of the mainland.

Comment: IMO the term "mainland" is a way to differentiate between Chinese from the "mainland" vs Chinese from Hong Kong, so I would say it always excludes Hong Kong.  Usage: "Have you visited China? I've visited Hong Kong but not Mainland China"

Comment: @EdmundYeung99, as seen from Hong Kong, definitely. But as seen from Taiwan, it _could_ designate the PRC including HK & Macau.

Comment: @jcaron even in Taiwan, "mainland" *excludes* Hong Kong and Macau. We can agree to disagree

Comment: Indeed , as far as I understand  it , like @jcaron said Mainland is excluding all territories that are / were separated from the main China Government ( Taiwan, HK, macau ). It is better conceived like mainland VS. Islands.  ( I even heard of Hainan people refering to "mainland" - but in different context )

Comment: Similarly, from the perspective of Puerto Rico, the term "Mainland US" includes islands such as Manhattan, Key West, Nantucket, and the Hawaiian Islands as much as it does Kansas. It's a political term that has a vague, but not exact, correspondence with physical geography.